# SOQL and Apex - Taking SOQL out of the for loop

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

I have 2 objects, say object 1 and object 2.
I first iterate over a collection of object 1 records.

```
Id Object2Id = 'Some Id';
for (Object1 obj1 : objectOneCollection ) {

    String query = 'SELECT Id FROM Object2 WHERE Id =:' + Object2Id  + ' AND ' + obj1.SOQLClause__c;

    List<Object2> list = Database.query(query);

    //do some processing with list

}
```

Hope my code says it all. I know having this Database.query() inside the above for loop is a bad practice. In other words, having SOQL inside for loops is something we are not supposed to do.

Can you help me to find a way to take this Database.query() out of the for loop making sure it still matches my requirement ?

Because, there is a field in Object1 containing a string to be matched in the where clause of object2.

Comment: I'm curious why you're storing your soql clauses on an object/record. This seems like a bad approach and more like an XY problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Agree with above and want to stress that you're opening yourself up to SOQL injection, which could be one of the things that @Programmatic means by "bad approach". The only (messy and inelegant) thing I can think is to take all of your SOQL clauses and `OR` them together into one big megaquery string, but beware of the 20k character limit on SOQL query length.